# Threads with huge time delay difference running sequentially

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I'm currently looking for a way to add TCP/IP communication to my application written in pyQt. While none of code i have tested appeared to work(in most cases it just freezed GUI) i started to investigate threading.

Found some code on stack and added sleep delays to it. I've read some information about threads running sequentially and i think i understand a bit how threading works, but the result i get is really not what i would expect.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import time
import threading

class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        QtWidgets.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.show()
        self.background = MyThread(self)
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.background.process)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.background.process2)
        t.start()
        t2.start()
        self.background.notify.connect(self.notify)
        self.background.notify2.connect(self.notify2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def notify(self):
        print("I have been notified")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def notify2(self):
        print("I have been notified two")

class MyThread(QtCore.QObject):

    notify = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    notify2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.should_continue = True

    def process(self):
        while self.should_continue:
            # Here, do your server stuff.
            time.sleep(0.001)
            self.notify.emit()

    def process2(self):
        while self.should_continue:
            # Here, do your server stuff.
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.notify2.emit()

def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why do i get:

```
I have been notified
I have been notified two
I have been notified two
I have been notified
I have been notified
I have been notified two
I have been notified
I have been notified two
```

instead of something like

```
I have been notified
I have been notified two
I have been notified
I have been notified
I have been notified
I have been notified
I have been notified
```

Shouldn't be the ratio of notify to notify2 prints number equal to time delays ratio ?

Comment: There is documentation that [sleep is interrupted to handle a signal before python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep).
Also another curious thing is that `self.background.notify2` was not connected in the code that you shared so how does notify2 pyQtSlot even get invoked?

Comment: Just to safe you future pain: You want to use `QThreads` for Qt stuff rather than normal `threading.Thread`s. There are some funky things going on with signals otherwise. Also: In my experience QtGUI elements are NOT threadsafe so you want to use signals for every interaction.

Comment: Typo: change `self.background.notify.connect(self.notify2)` to `self.background.notify2.connect(self.notify2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have connected wrong method to the wrong signal. `process2` emits `notify2`, not `notify`, so you have to change:

```py
self.background.notify.connect(self.notify)
self.background.notify.connect(self.notify2)
```

to

```py
self.background.notify.connect(self.notify)
self.background.notify2.connect(self.notify2)
```

And it will work as it should.

Comment: It works different but still the ratio of notify to notify2 prints is not equal time delays ratio, shouldn't it ?

Comment: I've changed timers to 1s/5s (for second method) to reduce output and get a clearer idea, [output looks as expected](https://i.imgur.com/4SdbaZB.png)

Comment: If so, is it some print method execution time issue then ?

Comment: If you're experiencing an issue, it probably has something to do with Python's native `threading` being used instead of `QThread`. From my (and other commenters) experience, it sometimes gets weird result, especially with small periods like yours.